# Call PrimeFaces dialog from backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I want when user in not logged-in, after clicking the `Add To Card` button, the `Login` dialog should appears.

Here is `Book.xhtml`:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Add To Card"
                     actionListener="#{booksBean.orderBook()}" 
                     class="QtyBtn">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" rendered="@form"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This is bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class BooksBean implements Serializable {
...
public void orderBook() {
...

    if (currentUser == null) {  // show the login dialog
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("Login");
    }
```

But `Login.xhtml` not opened.

Comment: You should not mix `<f:ajax>` with `<p:commandButton>`. Use `<p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"/>` instead. If the `orderBook()` is invoked and the specified condition is precisely satisfied, then this should work but this should be done using XHTML in a more intuitive way.

Comment: @Tiny `orderBook()` is invoked now, and my problem is just in opening of dialog.

Comment: @Tiny: `<p:commandButton>` is already ajaxified. No need to add an `<*:ajax>` at all.

Comment: @Kukeltje : It is needed, when there is a need to list some specific components with `process` and `update` (in this case, `process` defaults to `@form` but `update` defaults to `@none`. Hence, it needs to be explicit as the OP needs to update the form).

Comment: @Kukeltje : Yes, it is not needed. A `<p:commandButton>` itself has `process` and `update` attributes. Sorry, I forgot to consider them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you want to do is to use PrimeFaces Dialog Framework(DF). 
DF let's you open XHTML view in a dialog

1. Add this to your faces-config.xml

   ```xml
   <application>
     <action-listener>
       org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
     </action-listener>
     <navigation-handler>
       org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
     </navigation-handler>
     <view-handler>
       org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler
     </view-handler>
   </application>
   ```

2. Create your login.xhtml page as
   any XHTML page.
3. Add the corresponding outcome to your faces-config.xml. For example,

   ```xml
   <navigation-case>
     <from-outcome>Login</from-outcome>
     <to-view-id>/pages/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
     <redirect />
   </navigation-case>
   ```
4. Open the dialog with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("Login");`

Note that the DF opens the new dialog inside a frame.

Comment: Which is ALL in the PrimeFaces documentation